# Colorbar with matplotlib and rasterio

Tags: python, legend, rasterio, matplotlib

I am having trouble generating a colorbar for two raster plots. I could not manage to install basemaps in my Mac so I am forced to use matplotlib.

```
import rasterio
from matplotlib import pyplot

april_2019rain = rasterio.open('…/rain_0419Vis.tif')

april_2020rain = rasterio.open('…/rain_0420Vis.tif')

fig, (axr, axg) = pyplot.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20,10))

show((april_2019rain), ax=axr, title='Total Precipitation April 2019').grid(True)

show((april_2020rain), ax=axg, title='Total Precipitation April 2020').grid(True)

cbar = fig.colorbar(april_2019rain)

pyplot.show()
```

I would really like to have the colorbar horizontally displayed at bottom of the plots.